# xamarin forms prism images dont display

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm creating a new *"Prism blank app (xamarin.Forms)"* project in vs
    2017 to develop an android application.

I can't seem to make an image show on the `MainView` when I set the source to the image name that is the mipmap=hdpi folder.

When I use a regular Xamarin Forms project I have a drawable folder that works fine. I have tried:

```
<Image Source="checkmate.png"></Image>
```

and also binding to the view model:

```
<Image Source="{Binding LogoImage}"></Image>


public string LogoImage
{
    get { return "checkmate.png"; }
    set { LogoIm`enter code here`age = value; }
}
```

Comment: Prism is an MVVM helper and DI container, it is not responsible for images. 99% of your app's problems will not be related to prism at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/default-resources?tabs=vswin) the `Resources/drawable` folder should be the default folder for images.

If there is no `Resources/drawable` folder in your Android project, create one and place your assets there. Also make sure, that the build action of the files you've added is *`AndroidResource`*.